# discord.py ticket commandd

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a ticket command it works but I'm trying to have it create a ticket channel in a specific category

```py
@bot.command()
async def support(ctx, *, reason = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes the message of the author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {user}', overwrites=overwrites)
    await channel.send(f"{user.mention}")
    supem = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} Created a ticket.", description= "", color=0x00ff00)
    supem.add_field(name="reason", value=f"``{reason}``")
    supem.set_footer(text=f"staff will be with you shortly")
    await channel.send(embed=supem)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel), the `create_text_channel` function takes a `category` parameter. If we pass the category to it; it'll create the channel in the specific category.

```py
@bot.command()
async def support(ctx, *, reason = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes the message of the author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }

    # categories are just channels, so `get_channel` will get your category
    category = await guild.get_channel(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID)
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {user}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)

    await channel.send(f"{user.mention}")
    supem = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} Created a ticket.", description= "", color=0x00ff00)
    supem.add_field(name="reason", value=f"``{reason}``")
    supem.set_footer(text=f"staff will be with you shortly")
    await channel.send(embed=supem)
```

Or, use `category.create_text_channel` instead.

```py
@bot.command()
async def support(ctx, *, reason = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes the message of the author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }

    # categories are just channels, so `get_channel` will get your category
    category = await guild.get_channel(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID)
    channel = await category.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {user}', overwrites=overwrites)

    await channel.send(f"{user.mention}")
    supem = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} Created a ticket.", description= "", color=0x00ff00)
    supem.add_field(name="reason", value=f"``{reason}``")
    supem.set_footer(text=f"staff will be with you shortly")
    await channel.send(embed=supem)
```

Comment: Ok thank you I will do this